# Is it possible to limit the varchar to a particular set of characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, varchar

I am creating a website in which a particular user data should contain only characters from a particular pre-specified set. I can verify the data using PHP, before inserting it into the database. But I would like to know if this is possible in MySQL itself.

> For instance, consider the **Username**. It should have characters only
>   from the **Alphanumeric set** and **underscore**. Verification of this data is
>   possible through PHP before inserting it into the database. But is it
>   possible to assign a constrain to the *Varchar column* to not allow any
>   string, with characters other than these, to be inserted into the
>   table?

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> Is it possible to assign a constraint to the Varchar column to not
>   allow any string, with characters other than these, to be inserted
>   into the table?

The answer is no. MySQL constraints aren't that clever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any other way to do this? I'm not very educated on stored procedures, but I guess that only makes it slower. Also any other ways? like using another data type or something? I know about SETs which can limit the user input to only the contents of the set, but only one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Let's say we want to only allow letters a, c, and t as well as all the digits 0-9. We can create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER allowACT09 BEFORE INSERT
ON tbl1
FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.col1 NOT REGEXP '^[act0-9]*$' THEN
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000';
  END IF;
END//
```

Setting the signal 45000 blocks the insert, and the condition is a regular expression that allows any number of letters a, c, t, and/or digits 0-9.

- `aaac1t005a` would be permitted
- `aad` would not, and neither would `d11`
- an empty VARCHAR would be allowed, if you want to disallow it, change `*` to `+`.